# Teleric reports - nested tables

Tags: c#, wpf, telerik, telerik-reporting

I want to make table B nested in other table A.
Table A has more than one record so for each I want to print on report sub table.

I have object where one of properties is List

So it should look like that:

```
Tab A record 1
==Tab B(from A rec1) record 1
==Tab B(from A rec1) record 2

Tab A record 2
==Tab B(from A rec2) record 1

Tab A record 3
==Tab B(from A rec3) record 1
==Tab B(from A rec3) record 2
==Tab B(from A rec3) record 3
```

I've tried tables in list but i'm kind of confused about it and if someone could lend me a hand i would be gratefull.

Comment: You can you SubReports.
See this answer - http://stackoverflow.com/a/7803027/2085954
Hope this will help


  [1]: